# No such interface supported (0x80004002) in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, directshow.net

I'm trying to port [DirectShowLib](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/) for .NET Standard. I have no problem while casting `Xml2Dex` to `IXml2Dex` interface in .NET Framework 4.6.2. However, I've got `InvalidCastException` in .NET Core 3.1.

#### COM Import

```
[ComImport, SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity,
InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual),
Guid("18C628ED-962A-11D2-8D08-00A0C9441E20")]
public interface IXml2Dex
{
    // Interface implementation..
}

[ComImport, Guid("18C628EE-962A-11D2-8D08-00A0C9441E20")]
public class Xml2Dex
{
}
```

### Test

```
// works on .NET Framework 4.6.2, failed on .NET Core 3.1
object xml2Dex = (IXml2Dex) new Xml2Dex();
Assert.IsTrue(xml2Dex is IXml2Dex);
```

#### Exception

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'DirectShowLib.DES.Xml2Dex' to interface type
> 'DirectShowLib.DES.IXml2Dex'. This operation failed because the
> QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID
> '{18C628ED-962A-11D2-8D08-00A0C9441E20}' failed due to the following
> error: No such interface supported (0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

Running the test in `STAThread` mode does fix the issue. But why it works on .NET Framework without using single-threaded mode? Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Your *real* question is how to [expose .NET Core components to COM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/native-interop/expose-components-to-com). COM libraries are architecture-specific. If you want to use a x86 component, your application has to be an x86 application too. Another snag is that [.NET Core doesn't create TLBs automatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/native-interop/expose-components-to-com#additional-notes)

Comment: BTW 10 years is a *very* long time in Windows. Most of the DirectX functionality has been superseded by UWP and the related services. Chances are, whatever it is you're looking in DirectShow is available as a UWP service, or as a different API. Or even a different environment, eg Unity3D

Comment: Core's support for COM is not as good as Framework's. Supposedly there are improvements coming in .NET 5.0 but I would not count on them. As @PanagiotisKanavos says, COM is dead and you need to move on.

Comment: No proxy for this interface, STA is a rock-hard requirement.  My crystal ball says that your original code was a Winforms project or written in VB.NET.  Which make the main thread of a project STA by default.  The VB.NET behavior is especially naughty btw.